# npm_install `1 high severity vulnerability` node version: 12.18.3

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, node-modules

Installed wss to my Node_modules folder, it has also installed something Called istanbul? is this normal? When installing Wss it installed 47 other packages.. Not sure if that is supposed to happen or if something went wrong. Tried updating the package.json file anyway and it has given some errors that I don't really understand.

Terminal Output is below:

```
[letlziml@premium88 ~]$ source /home/letlziml/nodevenv/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/12/bin/activate && cd /home/letlziml/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g https
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/letlziml/nodevenv/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/12/lib/package.json': No such file or directory
+ https@1.0.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.457s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g ws
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/letlziml/nodevenv/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/12/lib/package.json': No such file or directory
+ ws@7.3.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.434s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g wss
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/letlziml/nodevenv/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/12/lib/package.json': No such file or directory
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
+ wss@3.3.4
added 47 packages from 148 contributors in 3.006s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g osln: creating symbolic link `/home/letlziml/nodevenv/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/12/lib/package.json': No such file or directory
+ os@0.1.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.511s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (nodetest) ^C
Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters and name can no longer contain capital letters.
package name: (nodetest) npm WARN init canceled
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm int -y

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/letlziml/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.6 /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm

Did you mean one of these?
    init
    it
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm init -y
Wrote to /home/letlziml/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/package.json:

{
  "name": "NodeTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g os
+ os@0.1.1
updated 1 package in 0.377s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g fs
+ fs@0.0.1-security
added 1 package in 0.341s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g url
+ url@0.11.0
added 3 packages from 3 contributors in 0.748s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g util
+ util@0.12.3
added 27 packages from 17 contributors in 2.589s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g path
+ path@0.12.7
added 4 packages from 2 contributors in 0.772s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g http
+ http@0.0.1-security
added 1 package in 0.351s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g https
+ https@1.0.0
updated 1 package in 0.326s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g crypto
npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
+ crypto@1.0.1
added 1 package in 0.327s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g events
+ events@3.2.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.358s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install -g querystring
+ querystring@0.2.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.341s
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm init -y
Wrote to /home/letlziml/public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest/package.json:

{
  "name": "NodeTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm install --save wss
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
npm WARN NodeTest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN NodeTest@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ wss@3.3.4
added 47 packages from 148 contributors and audited 47 packages in 43.684s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm audit
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOLOCK
npm ERR! audit Neither npm-shrinkwrap.json nor package-lock.json found: Cannot audit a project without a lockfile
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/letlziml/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T14_58_00_189Z-debug.log
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOLOCK
npm ERR! audit Neither npm-shrinkwrap.json nor package-lock.json found: Cannot audit a project without a lockfile
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/letlziml/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T14_58_24_982Z-debug.log
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm i --package-lock-only
npm WARN NodeTest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN NodeTest@1.0.0 No repository field.

audited 47 packages in 0.911s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOLOCK
npm ERR! audit Neither npm-shrinkwrap.json nor package-lock.json found: Cannot audit a project without a lockfile
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/letlziml/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T15_00_00_845Z-debug.log
[public_html/0/0/0/0/1/0/1/NodeTest (12)] [letlziml@premium88 NodeTest]$
```

Tried npm audit fix as the terminal has suggested, but it is saying that it needs manually review?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple questions here.  I'll try to cover them all.

> it has also installed something Called istanbul? is this normal?

Yes this is expected, `istanbul` is a dependency of `wss`.

> it installed 47 other packages.. Not sure if that is supposed to happen or if something went wrong

This sounds right, `wss` has 2 direct dependencies (`ws` and `istanbul`).  `ws` has no dependencies but `istanbul` has 14.  If you continue down the dependency chain further it should add up to 47 dependencies.

> Tried npm audit fix as the terminal has suggested, but it is saying that it needs manually review?

There is a security issue in the `ws` dependency for versions 2.0.0 to 3.3.0 (see audit snippet below).  Unfortunately `wss` has the `ws` dependency pinned to version ^2.3.1 (see https://github.com/ivoputzer/wss/blob/master/package.json#L34) so no compatible versions are patched.  This is an issue that needs to be fixed in the `wss` library.

```sh
$ npm audit
                                                                                
                       === npm audit security report ===                        
                                                                                
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ ws                                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >= 1.1.5 <2.0.0 || >=3.3.1                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ wss                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ wss > ws                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/550                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 1 high severity vulnerability in 47 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```